# What is the most efficient way to get an ordered list from a Tree (Diagram)?

Tags: c#, algorithm, tree, diagram

I'm using a diagram control which contains a Node with links to its parents as well as its children. I want to flatten the tree but in order. What's the fastest and most efficient way to do this; preferably in C#.

Here's an example of a tree. I'm having difficulties coming up with a good description of the order so I apologize. The order should list all nodes in order of their creation. For example, in the tree blow, a valid order would be (Root,A,B,C,G,D,H,E,F). This order guarantees that no Node is added to the list before its parent(s).

[image: Simple Diagram to demo my question]

Comment: What does "in order" mean? Would the root node be in the middle or at the beginning of the resulting list?

Comment: Basically, a node can't be inserted into the list without its parents already being there. The root would be at the beginning.

Comment: So order would be left to right at the leaf nodes? Or is there some other kind of sorting?

Comment: -1. Please show code for your slow/not-so-efficient way so this question can be answered. And comment why basic pre-order [traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) is not enough.

Comment: That's no tree, only a DAG.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your graph is no tree, since a node can have multiple parents. I assume you have a [directed acyclic graph (DAG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). Your ordered list is called a [toplogical ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of that directed graph, which exists if and only if the graph is acyclic. Luckily for you such an ordering can be produced with linear running time.

You can do this with a depth-first search starting from the root(s):

```
public static IEnumerable<Node> GetTopologicalGraphOrdering(IEnumerable<Node> roots)
{
    var list=new List<Node>();
    var visited=new HashSet<Node>();

    Action<Node> visit = null;
    visit = (n)=>
    {
       if(visited.Add(n)
       {
           foreach(Node child in n.Children)
           {
               visit(child);
           }
           list.Add(n)
       }
    }

    foreach(Node n in roots)
    {
       visit(n);
    }

    return list.Reverse();
}
```

(Untested notepad code)

Note that this naive implementation will cause a stack overflow for deep graphs. Switch to an explicit stack or an alternative algorithm, if that becomes a problem.

Read the wikipedia article [Topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the algorithm. My terminology is lacking so I appreciate your help. Can you elaborate more on what would cause a stack overflow? Would a circular reference cause that?

Comment: I was assuming that you don't have circular references. This code fails if there are circles. Wikipedia has a suggestion on how to handle that case.

Comment: I was talking about a graph where the chain from the lowest child to the root is very long (10000 nodes or so).